'cloudflared tunnel login' fails
I am trying to follow these instructions to create a tunnel from my localhost to a static domain created by cloudflare.
Create a locally-managed tunnel (CLI) · Cloudflare Zero Trust docs
I am stalled at the second step: ‘cloudflared tunnel login’ redirects me to ‘https://dash.cloudflare.com/argotunnel?aud=&callback=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.cloudflareaccess.org%2F_-asOzk-STJjLc3gdY23fYKlQ2LTM3PnsyDj2PGZsX8%3D’
But even after logging in on cloudflare from the browser, I still get ten messages like this:
‘Timestamp INF Waiting for login…’
Followed by ‘Failed to write the certificate due to the following error: Failed to fetch resource Your browser will download the certificate instead. You will have to manually copy it to the following path:’
However, the browser does not download the certificate. I have tried troubleshooting steps such as updating my browser or logging in with a different browser, to no avail.
How do I solve this error?
I was expecting for cloudflared to get a certificate that would help me with the next step, 'cloudflared tunnel create', but every tunnel management command is blocked because I cannot complete the 'cloudflared tunnel login' step.
